# Does gcc actually treat prototypes as functions and do their parameters have memory allocated?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, language-design

I have a strange specific question about the design of C and really about programming and language design in general.

This is the basis of it:  If I called a function that I had only prototyped, not assigned, would I be making a call to the actual C function data structure? In other words would this be a genuine function in every sense, or would the prototype be treated by gcc in a somewhat representative way, likely using a different data structure? The specific point within that question is about whether memory is allocated for the parameters declared with the prototype and whether or not an empty scope is created.

Gcc won't let you do this of course but if it would write the same machine code it normally would and I did try to call to a function that had only been prototyped, would the failure be:

1. prototypes aren't in all senses functions
2. the parameters aren't actually declarations, so they don't 
       represent allocated memory with proper addresses and normal 
       behaviors
3. since there were no curly brackets, gcc didn't, or couldn't, 
       generate a scope for this "function" to be added to the stack, 
       making the parameter declarations absurd since there is no scope 
       for them to be declared in (thus they aren't - thus no addresses)
4. there is a scope created, it's contents could otherwise go on the 
       stack, but execution dies because there were no instructions in 
       the function block to advance the program in memory
5. you can technically think of, and treat prototypes exactly like 
       functions, problem is they don't do anything!
6. something else I have completely missed

I have no idea why this question matters to me - but I guess if anything matters than everything matters - and it's kinda driving me crazy...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use gcc without the `-c` flag, it does two things: it compiles the source files to object and files and then it links the object files into the final executable (or library) file. So in that sense you can think of it as two tools, in fact for the linking step gcc does call the separate tool ld.

Now what happens when gcc sees a function prototype? It stores information about the function's signature in its internal data structures, so it knows how to typecheck calls to the function and how to generate code for the function calls (depending on the types, it might have to insert code for implicit conversions and the generated code looks different when calling variadic functions for example). A prototype does not cause any actual code to be generated.

When gcc sees an actual function definition, it also stores the same information in its internal data structures, but it also generates code for the function's body and stores the name of the function and the address of the generated code in the object's symbol table.

Now for function calls the compiler does the same thing for a merely-prototyped function as it does for an actually implemented function. In fact, it doesn't even know whether a definition for a function exists or not because the compiler only sees one c file (or rather one compilation unit) at a time and the definition might well live in another file. So what does the compiler do? It pushes the arguments onto the system stack and/or stores them in registers, depending on the number and types of arguments and the calling convention. Then it adds a call to the function using the function's name as a symbol.

This will work regardless of whether all the functions are defined or not. You will not get an error for undefined functions if you only do `gcc -c`.

Now what does ld do? It goes through all the object files and copies their contents together into the final executable or library file. While doing so it replaces the symbolic names of functions and variables with their actual address in the executable. This is the part where you get an error if a function is not defined.

So what would happen if it did let you call undefined functions? Well, it can't. It doesn't refuse to create an executable when you call undefined functions as a sort of sanity check, it refuses to create the executable *because it can't*. When there's no function definition, there's no address with which to replace the symbol. So it's just not possible to link the files.

So I guess the answer is "a": Prototypes aren't functions in the sense that they don't exist in the resulting object file at all. A function will only exist in the object file that contains its actual definition and if such a file does not exist (or there's more than one), that's an error.

Comment: Wow, super concise and straightforward - thank you for that!
Still trying to understand some of the underlying behaviors under the C ecosystem before I go bumbling into assembly...

Answer (score 2):

> a) prototypes aren't in all senses functions

correct they are not functions, just declarations to assist the compiler.

> b) the parameters aren't actually declarations, so they don't 
>       represent allocated memory with proper addresses and normal 
>       behaviors

the whole of the prototype is a declaration, a prototype, no code generated.

> c) since there were no curly brackets, gcc didn't, or couldn't, 
>       generate a scope for this "function" to be added to the stack, 
>       making the parameter declarations absurd since there is no scope 
>       for them to be declared in (thus they aren't - thus no addresses)

again no curly braces it is a declaration or a prototype, it does not generate code it is a definition used to assist the compiler when real code calls that function.  It is a function though a "function prototype"

> d) there is a scope created, it's contents could otherwise go on the 
>       stack, but execution dies because there were no instructions in 
>       the function block to advance the program in memory

the stack has nothing to do with this even if it were real code.  that is target and implementation defined.

> e) you can technically think of, and treat prototypes exactly like 
>       functions, problem is they don't do anything!

they are function definitions so that the generation of calls to those functions are prepared correctly.  Before you call one function from another in C you have to define it either completely define it for real or a prototype.

> f) something else I have completely missed

No you have it.

There are actually three tools involved.  The compiler makes assembly language, the assembler assembles that into an object repeat for each source file, then the linker links all those together.  if the compiler sees a item a global variable or function not defined in that compile of that file and its includes, then it leaves information for the linker to link the objects together, so that the linker can resolve that external with the addresses it has defined for that item.

so

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x );
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(fun1(x)+1);
}
```

I could use extern (see below) or not, one might argue that is the correct thing but gcc doesnt seem to care.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -O2 -save-temps fun0.c
```

arm is easier to read and basically the most widely used instruction set.

Normally gcc deletes the temporary files, even with a -c it is calling the assembler

fun0.s

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "fun0.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun0
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun0, %function
fun0:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, lr}
    bl  fun1
    pop {r4, lr}
    add r0, r0, #1
    bx  lr
    .size   fun0, .-fun0
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.2.0"
```

generating an object file which disassembles to

```
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun1>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

just the code for that function, not obvious to the average reader but the call (bl) to fun1 is not complete it has to be filled in later by the linker to connect the two.  there is no fun1 code here at all, it was just a prototype so that gcc could create fun0 correctly.

fun1

```
extern unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(fun2(x)+2);
}
```

used the extern this time

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun2>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

doesnt change things it was just a prototype.

```
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int  x)
{
    return(x+3);
}
```

call it the end of the line here and just return something

```
00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

So far we have compiled to assembly language for each C source file and then assembler was called by the compiler to make an object file, but those object files are not programs really until linked, there are ways to use them in special cases, but the design of this toolchain is to use the whole chain compiler, assembler, linker.

If I add to this a bootstrap, just enough to be a real program

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    mov r0,#0
    bl fun0
    b .
```

and then link it all together

```
00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    8008:   eb000000    bl  8010 <fun0>
    800c:   eafffffe    b   800c <_start+0xc>

00008010 <fun0>:
    8010:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    8014:   eb000002    bl  8024 <fun1>
    8018:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
    801c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    8020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008024 <fun1>:
    8024:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    8028:   eb000002    bl  8038 <fun2>
    802c:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
    8030:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
    8034:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00008038 <fun2>:
    8038:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
    803c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Most of the code was position independent, the calls (bl, branch links) were as well, but need a pc relative offset, the linker did that job of modifying those instructions so that they connected to the relative address of the function being called.  notice the stack was not involved here, other than to preserve the return address, the pushing of r4 is for stack alignment could have used almost any register there other than r4, it was strictly to keep the stack on a 64 bit boundary.

The prototypes were just prototypes in order to get the call right.  If you leave the prototype off, then it will assume ints and declare a warning.

```
fun1.c: In function ‘fun1’:
fun1.c:5:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fun2’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return(fun2(x)+2);
            ^~~~

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun2>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800002    add r0, r0, #2
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

but what if it wasnt an int or something we didnt get lucky with or we prototyped it wrong.

```
extern float fun2 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(fun2(x)+2);
}
```

producing

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun2>
   8:   e3a01101    mov r1, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__aeabi_fadd>
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__aeabi_f2uiz>
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

gccs implicit declaration so that it can keep going would have been wrong and the code would not have worked.

It is possible that some compiler other than gcc (or some future version of gcc) will actually generate code if you dont put extern up front.  Because of peoples habits that is probably bad as a lot of existing code would break, but unless the standard says otherwise a compiler writer might interpret this

```
void more_fun ( void );
```

for example as a complete function, and generate some code, but this

```
unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int );
```

might be a little harder for that compiler to wing it, would want them at least to complain that there wasnt a variable name.

I dont know that I have seen a compiler that generates code from a prototype, and have seen volumes of code that would create problems if the compiler tried to.  you would have multiple definitions of each function that the linker wouldnt know what to do with.  It just doesnt make sense.

EDIT

I assume you mean compiler/toolchain design in general not language design necessarily.  Some languages were always meant to be compiled (Pascal, C, C++), some were meant to be interpreted (JAVA, Pyton, Perl, BASIC), but that doesnt mean you cant compile them or dont. JAVA and Python are compiled languages but the designers did both the language and implementation, and they were meant to be compiled to a generic machine code, a virtual machine code, that a virtual machine that is target specific is created to interpret.  Pascal was that way too at one time (arguably Small C is as well)  But gcc for example as a JAVA front end that will produce native backend code if I understand right, maybe I am wrong on that but thought I saw that.  Python may or may not have a way to be compiled to the target, you would need libraries in each case to fill in the gaps for the virtual machines system calls (virtual instructions which are actually system calls not CISC/RISC like individual instructions that operate on memory or registers).

Designing the language is in part the syntax and then a desired implementation.  The language itself does not make it object oriented for example, has nothing to do with it, the implementation of the compiler does or doesnt do that.  But when folks set out to design a language the often/sometimes push on the implementation of the compiler as well, JAVA and python very good examples.  Other languages (D I think) are meant to be compiled and take advantage of LLVM or GCC's ability to add new language front ends and take advantage of the existing backends.

So language design is too general of a topic, have to focus specifically on one like you did with C.

Answer (score 0):

> something else I have completely missed.

Yes. It would be a linker error. Nothing to do with the compiler whatsoever.